# Change image dynamically in Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

In my code I have defined the following:
`<s:Image id="test" x="50" y="50" width="30" height="30" click="onClick_clickHandler(event)" smooth="true" smoothingQuality="high" source="@Embed('icons/myImage_60_off.png')"/>`
What I want is to be able to change the source of the image every time the user clicks on the image - similar to the way favourites work on a browser.
I have no idea how to change the source of the image from my code.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it!
`public var image_loader:Loader;` // define a new loader 
`image_loader = new Loader();` // create the new loader at the desired location (in my case in the initialization method of the page 
`image_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, imageLoaded);` //add a listener and a function to assign to the listener 
depending on where the command has to be executed 
`image_loader.load(new URLRequest('location of the image'));` //this will load the image dynamically
`function imageLoaded(event:Event):void {image_Id.source = image_loader;}` //where image_Id is the id of the s:Image tag to be modified 
also, I had to remove the source from the s:Image tag previously posted 
The rest is just logic of the way the application needs to implement the functionality, so it's pretty much left to the developer's desires

Answer (score 0):

I had a hidden datagrid with my solution, because it started off with a visible one.

The image looked like this:

```
 <mx:Image top="153" left="10" right="10" bottom="5" source="{dgpick.selectedItem.ImageFile}" />
```

Every time someone clicks on the image, I would increase the selected index of the datagrid, and the labels will display the corresponding data, as they are also bound to its data.

The image can also have a link to an XML file that you can load like this:

```
<s:HTTPService id="Config"
                   url="config.xml"
                   result="resultHandler(event)"/>

private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void 
{
    ImagesURL = event.result.images.ImagesURL[iCounter];                

}
```

Every time someone clicks on the image, you can increase the counter, and so forth.

Hope this gives you some ideas.

There are 20 ways to do this.

If you need more code, add a comment, with what you need.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. The counter was my idea as well still, I don't really follow you. I already have one HTTPService in my view (to a server), can I use another one? Is this a safe approach? Also, can you be a little bit more specific please. I just started with Flash Builder and there are still concepts I don't grasp as I should.
I thought I could just use something like
`  counter%2 == 0  
img.source = new sourece of image //taken form an array  
else  
img.source = other source //the other value from the array  `
Thanks again